# Owin WSFederation infinite redirect after login

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, adfs

Im getting an infinite redirect after i logged in with ADFS 2.0.

My ConfigureAuth.cs is like

```
//defines default authentication to WSFederation
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

//Defines the MetadataAddress and realm
app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
{
      MetadataAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AdfsMetadataEndpoint"],
      Wtrealm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
});

//Defines WSFederation cookie as default authentication type
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
      AuthenticationType = WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
});
```

i can get to the ADFS login page, but when it returns to my app it keeps asking ADFS for a valid authentication, after 6 requests i get blocked by ADFS.

**UPDATE 1**

It turns out i needed to specify the Issuer, TokenEndpoint and the certificate key, for some reason owin didnt get these values from the metadata, so i ended up copying the values of the metadata and using them in the webconfig under appsettings.

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
           app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { });

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Wtrealm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
                AuthenticationType = WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,

                Configuration = getWsFederationConfiguration()
            }
        );
    }

    private static WsFederationConfiguration getWsFederationConfiguration()
    {
        WsFederationConfiguration configuration = new WsFederationConfiguration
        {
            Issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsFederation:trustedIssuer"],
            TokenEndpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsFederation:issuer"],
        };

        configuration.SigningKeys.Add(new X509SecurityKey(new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsFederation:trustedIssuerSigningKey"]))));

        return configuration;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out i needed to specify the Issuer, TokenEndpoint and the certificate key, for some reason owin didnt get these values from the metadata, so i ended up copying the values of the metadata and using them in the webconfig under appsettings.

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
           app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { });

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Wtrealm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
                AuthenticationType = WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,

                Configuration = getWsFederationConfiguration()
            }
        );
    }

    private static WsFederationConfiguration getWsFederationConfiguration()
    {
        WsFederationConfiguration configuration = new WsFederationConfiguration
        {
            Issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsFederation:trustedIssuer"],
            TokenEndpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsFederation:issuer"],
        };

        configuration.SigningKeys.Add(new X509SecurityKey(new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsFederation:trustedIssuerSigningKey"]))));

        return configuration;
    }
```

Comment: What lead you to determining that these missing pieces were causing the issue? I'm seeing something similar, but would like to understand why this would fix it before throwing it into our project.

Comment: @shortstuffsushi in my case (using ADFS 2.0) it was needed to specify the Issuer, TokenEndpoint and the certificate key to owin, so that owin could trigger the authentication mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

How do you trigger authentication? If it is through an [Authorize], do you happen to request special user or roles? If you request a role that the signed in user does not have, you'll end up bouncing around.
Also, you should change the order of your calls: first set the cookie middleware, then the protocol one.

Comment: yes i have an authorize override, i just validate if the user has a specific claim. But the issue was that for some reason owin wasnt getting the values i needed from the metadata(see update 1) thanks